# Can M.2 slots be combined? (And other questions)

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, pci-express, m.2, expansion-cards

I'm looking around on google for information about M.2, chiefly regarding using it for eGPUs, but information is scattered and I'm not really getting anywhere with it. I need some help.

-M.2 slots can supposedly only provide 4 lanes of PCIe instead of 16. **Will this cause compatibility issues** with GPUs, or will it only cause a bottleneck?

-**Is it possible to split an M.2 slot** into 2 or 4 slots? If there is, would each slot then only have 2 or 1 lanes of PCIe?

-Most laptops have a wifi card that uses an M.2 slot. **Is there any difference between this slot and slots meant for NVME drives?** Can they also be used for an eGPU, or for a second NVME drive?

-(This is the stupid question) **Can they be combined?** If I've got 2 M.2 slots with 4 lanes each, can they be made into a single one with 8 lanes? If the answer is somehow a yes, can this be done with connectors that have different amounts of lanes, for example one with 4 and another with 2?

-**Is it hotpluggable?** [The wikipedia article for PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#MINI-CARD) says that PCIe is hotpluggable with certain interfaces, but doesn't mention if that applies to M.2. The M.2 article doesn't say anything about hot-plugging. From how the PCIe wiki mentions other interfaces, I want to believe that it isn't hotpluggable, but it's vague to say the least.

Comment: “Can they be combined?” - No

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please have a look at the Asking -section [Help](https://superuser.com/help), there's good advice on [how to ask clear question that's easy to answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). You should research the questions first, then ask for clarifications. SE sites aren't discussion forums, but Q&A sites; the idea is that one can search for a question e.g. "Is it possible to split an M.2 slot into 2" to find answers. Hence asking multiple questions at one go isn't the best approach.

Comment: @Peregrino69 It seems like all the questions follow the guidelines you've linked. I did my best to research each of them, but didn't manage to find concrete answers. I'm no good at googling, sorry if the answers are out there anyways. The big issue with my post is that I asked multiple different questions at once. I'll be sure not to do that again. But, I've already gotten answers to all the questions. Should I delete this post? Should I leave it up? How should I proceed?

Comment: The issue with the question was the multiple questions, darn well-formulated they were. @user1686 gave you really good info. As for your googling skills... I just did a bit of testing, and put some of your questions with minor tweaks (like replacing "these slots" with "slots used for wi-fi cards") to Google and got a ton of results. So I'd say your search skills exceed mine, I have harder time myself as I tend to just use a few keywords :-D No point deleting a closed question :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Seems like there was a small misunderstanding, I thought you were the one to close the question because of the issues you noted, turns out another guy had closed it because it contained a lot of fluff text lol. I'm gonna do some edits and then see if I can reopen it, thanks for the tips either way 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -Is it possible to split an M.2 slot into 2 or 4 slots?

Some motherboards do support "PCIe bifurcation", but even on systems that do support it in general (e.g. for the full-size 16-lane slots into e.g. 4×4-lane), it's highly unlikely to be supported for the already-narrow M.2 ports.

However, there might be devices that have a whole PCIe bridge on them, allowing that bridge to have multiple ports. For example, if you start with [this](http://bplus.com.tw/ExtenderBoard/P4SM2.html) or [this](http://bplus.com.tw/ExtenderBoard/P14S-P14F.html) breakout cable of M.2 to a full-size PCIe slot, you might be able to combine it with [this](https://www.delock.de/produkt/90409/merkmale.html?f=s) or [this](https://www.amfeltec.com/flexible-x4-pci-express-4way-splitter/) PCIe splitter, and it might even work once in a blue moon.

The M.2 specification also apparently allows certain M.2 keys to provide two separate PCIe connections in the same slot, allowing [this](http://bplus.com.tw/ExtenderBoard/P11S-P11F.html) kind of breakout to exist (it's one of those companies who make adapters for anything-to-anything), but apparently no motherboards supporting this ever existed, so they weren't even able to test the product.

> If there is, would each slot then only have 2 or 1 lanes of PCIe?

With bifurcation, each slot would have dedicated lanes. (For example, an x16 slot could act as two x8 slots or four x4 slots.)

With a bridge/switch/splitter, I believe all downstream ports would *share* the single upstream connection (which would be as wide as the bridge supports), just like it works with Ethernet switches or USB hubs, but I'm not 100% sure if I have this part right.

> -Most laptops have a wifi card that uses an M.2 slot. Is there any difference between this slot and slots meant for NVME drives? Can they also be used for an eGPU, or for a second NVME drive?

In theory yes, but from what I've heard, many laptops have deliberate firmware restrictions that only accept certain "manufacturer approved" cards in this slot, so in practice most likely no.

Also, I *think* the "Wi-Fi card" slot uses a different M.2 keying ("E" key), which provides USB 2.0 pins for the Bluetooth controller that co-exists on the Wi-Fi card (due to them sharing the same 2.4 GHz radio), instead of the SATA pins that typical "SSD" M.2 slots have alongside PCIe.

The opposite usage is [possible](http://bplus.com.tw/Adapter/PN15A.html); an M.2 Wi-Fi card can be connected to a full-size PCIe slot (and as the adapter manufacturer here shows, also wants a connection to USB).

> -(This is the stupid question) Can they be combined? If I've got 2 M.2 slots with 4 lanes each, can they be made into a single one with 8 lanes? If the answer is somehow a yes, can this be done with connectors that have different amounts of lanes, for example one with 4 and another with 2?

I've never heard of PCIe slots supporting this.

> -Is it hotpluggable? The wikipedia article for PCIe says that PCIe is hotpluggable with certain interfaces, but doesn't mention if that applies to M.2. The M.2 article doesn't say anything about hot-plugging. From how the PCIe wiki mentions other interfaces, I want to believe that it isn't hotpluggable, but it's vague to say the least.

Both kinds of slots go to the same "controller", and would probably be able to recognize hot-plugged or hot-removed cards at software level, but the M.2 connector doesn't seem to be physically designed with that in mind.

Specifically, I'd guess no based on:

1. The identical length of all pins on most M.2 cards. Full-size PCI Express cards have one pin that is deliberately shorter (in fact, the dedicated "Hotplug Detect" pin), and is therefore guaranteed to only make contact after the card is fully inserted and the rest of the pins have made contact. There's no equivalent for this in M.2 slots.
2. The "PCI Express Card Electromechanical Specification" document which defines the form factor of full-size PCIe cards has an entire section regarding "Hot Insertion and Removal". Meanwhile, the "PCI Express M.2 Specification", at least version 1.0 (2013) that I happen to have acquired, has no mention of hot insertion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a great answer :)